# Android - Set digital clock to display time only in 24 hour format

Tags: android

I have the code below in order to display the digital clock. Essentially it works fine but I want it to display only 24 hour format hence if the user were to change the format in the settings between 24 or 12 hour fomrats it will not affect the time displayed in my app.

```
    DigitalClock digital_clock_4inches = (DigitalClock)findViewById(R.id.bge_digital_clock_4inches);
digital_clock_4inches.setTypeface(bge_currentDateandTimeFont_4inches);
```

I understand taking over the DigitalClock code as seen here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/DigitalClock.java is an option and if this were the case wht does one change in the code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

TIMER:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
},0,1000);//Update text every second
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own clock using Calendar that shows 24 hour format of time.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND); 
int min= c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
int hour= c.get(Calendar.HOUR); 
if(c.get(Calendar.AM_PM))//if returns pm add 12 to hour
Textview.append(hour + ":" + min + ":" + seconds );
```

Use a Timer class to update it every second.

Comment: Hi Arju, thanks for the assistance. I've created the timer but was wondering about the syntax in the run() method ... i.e.             I've adjusted my code above to regarding the timer is just created.

Answer (score 0):

In the timer code, you should update the textviews text:

```
Timer timer = new Timer()
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {
seconds++;
if(seconds == 60){
min+=1;
seconds = 0;}

if(min == 60){
hour+=1;
min = 0;}

if(hour == 24){
hour = 0;
}

Textview.append(hour + ":" + min + ":" + seconds );

}},0,1000);//Update text every second
```